# Is there a way to integrate SQL Table Schema Comparison/Crossover into CI/CD gitlab?

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

**Context:**

I have a project where we can find 2 SQL databases. The first one is db_prod (in production) and the second one is db_test (in test).
Sometimes, I'm updating my db_test table schemas, adding some columns.

**Problem:**

In my gitlab CI/CD pipeline, I want to integrate the changes of my db_test table schemas into my db_prod table schemas (I am not speaking about data, just table structures) during the CD phasis.

**Some important points:**

I saw there are already some softwares and IDEs (like visual studio) which can help you to compare table structures and to create the update script, but I didn't find a way to integrate it in CI/CD pipelines. The only way I figured out is to develop my own script.

**Question:**

Do you know/Have you some piece of advice to integrate "SQL comparison and structure crossover between 2 databases" into CI/CD gitlab pipeline ? :)

Thank for your answers!

PS : I don't want some softwares I need to pay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for any other software, it can all be done within a Gitlab CI Pipeline. Here's an example job to connect to a QA database and run some queries (for example, creating tables):

```yaml
stages:
  - database_setup
  ...

Setup QA Database:
  stage: database_setup
  image: mysql:8.0
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    # Run some queries
    - mysql -h ${QA_MYSQL_HOST} -p ${QA_MYSQL_PORT} -u ${QA_MYSQL_USER} -p${QA_MYSQL_PASSWORD} -e "create database qa_database_name;"
    - mysql -h ${QA_MYSQL_HOST} -p ${QA_MYSQL_PORT} -u ${QA_MYSQL_USER} -p${QA_MYSQL_PASSWORD} -e "create table example_table (id int, name, varchar(50));"
```

This is just a dumb example, but this job uses a Docker image that has the mysql server and client software installed, but in this example we only need the client as we're connecting to a remote database server (specified by the `QA_MYSQL_HOST`, `QA_MYSQL_PORT`, `QA_MYSQL_USER`, and `QA_MYSQL_PASSWORD` variables that are CI Variables defined in the Project settings in Gitlab).

The job for setting up the prod database would be similar, but you'd connect to a different database, run different queries, etc.

Comment: Thank for your answer. 
So, what you are suggesting me is to deal with changes by comparing tables and writting a script to apply these changes into my database, in production with a CI job.

That's what I want to do, because I'm not finding a "better" solution. 
I'm gonna try it :)

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer solved your issue, you can upvote it and mark it as Accepted.